# Getting an error Unable to locate appender "jmeter-log" for logger config "root" while running and creating the html dashboard for my jmeter scripts

Tags: html, jmeter, dashboard

I am trying to create Jmeter HTML report through CSV with the help of command  but getting below error in my CMD. Please help me what i need to change or enhance for getting the reults

2020-07-23 16:47:20,385 main ERROR Null object returned for File in Appenders.
2020-07-23 16:47:20,409 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "jmeter-log" for logger config "root"
An error occurred: Cannot read test results file : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is [`Cannot read test results file`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/dashboard/ReportGenerator.java#L129)  and it occurs when you point JMeter to not-existing file or the file cannot be read (you don't have permissions to open the file in that location)

The other problem is with [JMeter logging configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), either your [log4j2.xml file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/log4j2.xml) is broken or again you don't have proper read/write permissions to the folder where JMeter is installed. Try running the terminal with [elevated rights](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-run-a-program-with-elevated-permissions/) and both should go away

Comment: can you please look into the following query as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63053225/3928743

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing the latest version of Jmeter, 5.3. After that, no more logging/summarizer errors.